# Loop back to start after setInterval

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I have a list containing images and what I'm trying to do is show an image every second (whilst keeping the previous images displayed), then when all images have been shown - hide all and then start the process again. I have managed to create the effect I want using setInterval but I don't know how to then hide all and start again, also the number of images in the list will vary so it'll be an unknown amount.

This is what I have so far

```
         <ul id="slider">
            <li><img src="images/image1.jpg" width="300px"/></li>
            <li><img src="images/image2.jpg" width="200px"/></li>
            <li><img src="images/image3.jpg" width="100px"/></li>
            <li><img src="images/image1.jpg" width="50px"/></li>
            <li><img src="images/image2.jpg" width="20px"/></li>

        </ul>

        $(document).ready(function () {


        /*Slider*/
        var slides = $("#slider > li > img");
        $(slides).hide();
        $(slides).parents("#slider>li:nth-child(1)").find("img").show();

        var x = 1;
        setInterval(function () {

            $(slides).parents("#slider>li:nth-child(" + x + ")").find("img").show();
            if (x == slides.length)

                x = 1;
            else

            x++;
        }, 1000);
        /*End*/           
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the condition to reset `x` to 1; use the same condition block to reset the state of the slideshow. Then, you can make things a littleless repetitive with a couple of helper functions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var slides = $("#slider > li > img");
  function showImage(x) {
    $(slides)
      .parents("#slider>li:nth-child(" + x + ")")
      .find("img")
      .show();
  }
  var x;
  function reset() {
    x = 1;
    $(slides).hide();
    showImage(1);
  }
  reset();

  setInterval(function() {
    if (x > slides.length) {
      reset();
    } else {
      showImage(x);
      x++;
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create functin  and check condition based on length and hide your image.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  /*Slider*/
  var slides = $("#slider > li > img");
  var length = slides.length;
  $(slides).hide();
  $(slides).parents("#slider>li:nth-child(1)").find("img").show();

  var x = 1;
  setInterval(function() {
    function loop() {
      $(slides).parents("#slider>li:nth-child(" + x + ")").find("img").show();
      if (x == slides.length + 1) {
        $(slides).hide();
        x = 1;
      } else

        x++;
    }
    loop();
    return loop;

  }, 1000);


  /*End*/
});
```

```css
#slider > li {
  list-style: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="slider">
  <li><img src="images/image1.jpg" width="300px" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/image2.jpg" width="200px" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/image3.jpg" width="100px" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/image1.jpg" width="50px" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/image2.jpg" width="20px" /></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest fix for you is adding a simple:

```
$(slides).hide()
```

when you reached slides.length.

A more intuitive and "easier" solution in my opinion is using an async function instead.

```
$(document.ready(() => {
      let slides = $('slider>li>img');
      $(slides).hide();

      // Calling loop without await causes it to run without blocking the main function
      loop(slides, 1000);
})

const loop = async (slides, duration) => {
      slides.forEach(slide => {
            $(slide).show();

            // sleep for duration ms
            await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, duration));
      }

     // After looping through all slides, hide them
     $(slides).hide();
}
```

If you want to loop through the "loop" function indefinitely you can create a new async function:

```
const looploop = async (slides, duration) => {
       // Using the await keyword will wait for the loop function to finish,
       // And only then will it call it again.
       // The trick here is that the waiting is in the async function scope
       // so if you were to call looploop without await in the main function
       // it wouldn't block it.
       while(true) {
             await loop(slides, duration);
       }
}
```

Async programming in js transforms how you think about long running tasks such as this one. It allows you to write non-blocking functions in an iterative way causing it to become "simple" and "easy".

Comment: This is invalid, since foreach isn't promise-aware (everything is hidden at once), and the function you've passed in to foreach isn't marked async (syntax error to use await within a non-async function).